# CakePHP 3 - Rename controller in routes.php

Tags: url-routing, cakephp-3.0

What would be the correct way to reroute all actions from `fakeController` to `controller1` using Cake's routing engine?

I'd like to reroute actions `index` and any other actions and also parameters.

`app/fake/` => `app/controller1/`

`app/fake/action1` => `app/controller1/action1`

`app/fake/action2/any/params` => `app/controller1/action2/any/params`

Is it possible with just one line of code?

**Why I am doing this?** - because in CakePHP 3 the routes are case-sensitive. I'd like to keep my controllers names UpperCase, but it results in paths like `app/Users/login`, if I write `users` it says `usersController not found`. If there is a way around this, I wouldn't need all this rerouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default route is case-sensitive, yes, however by default there should be fallbacks defined using the `InflectedRoute` class, which behave as known from 2.x, ie it will inflect `users` to `Users` (as of 3.1.0 the default is `DashedRoute`, which inflects too).

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.0.4/config/routes.php#L73**

If you want this to be the default behavior (note that this is relatively slow) for all routes, then simply set this to be the default via `Router::defaultRouteClass()`

```php
Router::defaultRouteClass('InflectedRoute');
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.0.4/config/routes.php#L42**

or in order to restrict it to a specific scope, use the `fallbacks()` method.

```php
$routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.0.4/config/routes.php#L73**

Alternatively you could create appropriate routes for all your controllers, similar to as shown in your apps `routes.php` file:

```php
Router::scope('/', function (\Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder $routes) {
    // ...

    $routes->connect('/users', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/users/:action/*', ['controller' => 'Users']);

    $routes->connect('/foos', ['controller' => 'Foos', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/foos/:action/*', ['controller' => 'Users']);

    // and so on...
});
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.0.4/config/routes.php#L60-L62**

See **[Cookbook > Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html)** for more information about routing.